# Slot not replaced

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I need replace "Default Slot" on new " I need replace this".
Why slot with name "btn" dont replace default component value? How fix it?

**HTML**

```
<div id="dropdown-sort-list">
  <dropdown-sort-list>
    <template v-slot:btn>
      I need replace this
    </template>
  </dropdown-sort-list>
</div>
```

**Component**

```
let dropdown = Vue.component('dropdown-sort-list', {
        props: {

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
            }
        },
        template: `
                <div class="dropdown">

                    <slot name="btn">
                       Default Slot
                    </slot>

                </div>
              `
    });
```

**Script**

```
var dropdownMix = dropdown.extend({
    mixins: [{
        data: function () {
            return {
                itemList: itemListData,
            }
        },
    }]
});

var dropdownEx = new dropdownMix({
    el: "#dropdown-sort-list",
});
```

Comment: the dropdownMix component, during the mount process, overwrites all the content within the div with id `dropdown-sort-list`, that's why it doesn't work

Comment: here is a jsfiddle with a possible solution. If this is what you want I will add it as answer https://jsfiddle.net/7fj2skwt/

Comment: Thanks fabruex. It works and now I understand it.

Comment: Glad it helped you, I added it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dropdownMix` component, during the mount process, overwrites all the content within the div with id `dropdown-sort-list`. That's why it doesn't work.

Here's a possible solution:

```html
<div id="mydiv">
    <dropdown-sort-list-mix>
        <template slot="btn">
            I need replace this
        </template>
    </dropdown-sort-list-mix>
</div>
```

```js
let dropdown = Vue.component('dropdown-sort-list', {
        props: {

        },
        data: function () {
            return {
            }
        },
        template: `
                <div class="dropdown">

                    <slot name="btn">
                       Default Slot
                    </slot>

                </div>
              `
    });

var dropdownMix = dropdown.extend({
    mixins: [{
        data: function () {
            return {
                itemList: itemListData,
            }
        },
    }]
});

Vue.component('dropdown-sort-list-mix',dropdownMix)

new Vue({
    el: '#mydiv'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Look like your vue version cant use `v-slot` , try to use `slot="btn"` instead of `v-slot:btn`